# Is a top-left origin coordinate system what's stopping this equation from working?

Tags: python, math, opencv

I am trying to implement this equation to determine the centre of a circle from three user-selected points: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates

First, the points are acquired and assembled into a list by means of this OpenCV mouse callback function:

```
def setupPoints(event, x, y, flags, points):
   #Populates a provided list 'points' with
   #three coordinates representing the edge of
   #a circle
   if points[0] == 0:
      points[0] = (x,y)
   elif points[1] == 0:
      points[1] = (x,y)
   else:
      points[2] = (x,y)
```

Then I pass the list of points to this function, which does the work:

```
def findCircle(p):
   #Returns the circle centre
   #from three provided points provided as tuples
   #in a list
   #See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates
   ax = float(p[0][0])
   ay = float(p[0][1])
   bx = float(p[1][0])
   by = float(p[1][1])
   cx = float(p[2][0])
   cy = float(p[2][1])

   d = 2*(ax*(by-cy)+bx*(cy-ay)+cx*(ay-by))
   centrex = ((pow(ax,2)+pow(ay,2))*(by-cy)+(pow(bx,2)+pow(by,2))*(cy-ay)+(pow(cx,2)+pow(cy,2))*(ay-by))/d
   centrey = ((pow(ax,2)+pow(ay,2))*(cx-bx)+(pow(bx,2)+pow(by,2))*(ax-cx)+(pow(cx,2)+pow(cy,2))*(bx-ax))/d

   return (int(round(centrex)), int(round(centrey)), int(round(d)))
```

However, it's not working.  The returned numbers aren't massively off, but they are definitely incorrect.  Could this be to do with the fact that the coordinate system used by OpenCV has its origin in the top-left of the image (points within the image are still positive, so it could be said to be counting 'backwards', vertically at least).

Or is that guess wrong?

Comment: Can you test with some numbers you do know, then you can pin the problem on the input numbers being of the wrong coordinate system. Do the maths manually so you know the answer, input numbers. Input numbers again in wrong coordinate system.

Comment: You were right to say that I should have checked it all on paper first.  As it happened, the function worked as expected, but at least after checking I could be confident that the problem wasn't in the findCircle function - this led me to find the solution (see below)

Answer (score 2):

More than likely it's because the operands of your division are both integers, so the result is a (floored) integer. In Python, `2/3 == 0`. This will throw off your calculations a little since they won't be rounded properly. Try dividing by `float(d)` rather than just `d`.

Comment: If you're using Python 2.2 or later, and this the issue, you can also future-proof your code by using `from __future__ import division` to use float division by default (int division is still available as the `//` operator).

Comment: I though any math operation with a float would always result in a float in python. Version permitting of course.

Comment: @Paystey if both numbers are integer, it uses integer division.  Otherwise, float division.  [As of python 3.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), float division is the default for the `/` operator, and int division the default for the `//` operator.  See [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-March/060886.html) for example.

Comment: Thank you, but d was already a float as it was created as the result of an operation on exclusively floats.  I just added a check to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question regarding whether the wonky (from a maths point of view, not a computer graphics points of view) coordinate system was preventing this from working is NO.

I simply forgot to add a check in my mouse callback function to make sure the event was a click and not simply a mouse movement; my points weren't what I was clicking!

Thanks for looking at this, maybe this will help someone in future...